# AVAudioSession Deactivated when I leave Channel Agora Voice Unity SDK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, agora.io, agora, agora-implementation

I am using Agora Voice Unity SDK for voice calling in my App.
I facing a problem that when I leave channel on iPhone . My button clicks sounds stops working.

by investigating I found "AVAudioSession" is deactivating on leaving channel.

Here is the Console Log Statement:

> "2023-08-04 01:03:29.359231-0700 AgoraVoicetest[1362:131944] [avas]     AVAudioSession_iOS.mm:1271  Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session."

This log appears when I leave channel.

Here is my code screenshot for leave channel.

[image: Leave Channel Function SS (C# , Unity)]

I have tried "DisableAudio()" function upon leaving channel.
Expected result: Upon leaving channel , only voice communication should be disabled/disconnect . Game media sounds (e.g: Button click sounds) should remain active.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

For others running into this issue on iOS, Agora's support team helped me with putting the following code before joining a channel:

```
_myRtcEngine.SetParameters("{\"che.audio.keep.audiosession\":true}");
```

The long and short of it is that iOS audio sessions are shared and Agora needs to make sure to return/restore that AVAudioSession